# '$' symbol in json - how to parse in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

My JSON looks like

```
var f =  { feed:                                                                                                                                                                                                             
{ '$':                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  { xmlns: 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom',                                                                                                                                                                       
    'xmlns:media': 'http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/',                                                                                                                                                             
   'xml:lang': 'en-US' },                                                                                                                                                                                      
 id: [ 'tag:github.com,2008:/bevry/feedr/commits/master' ],                                                                                                                                                     
link: [ [Object], [Object] ],                                                                                                                                                                                  
title: [ 'Recent Commits to feedr:master' ],                                                                                                                                                                   
updated: [ '2013-06-28T15:29:11-07:00' ],                                                                                                                                                                      
entry:                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  [ [Object]]
   }
 }
}
```

I am trying to parse it in javascript,

but if I do console.log(f.feed.$) it returns undefined.

Same with f.feed.$.title, f.feed['$'].title

Comment: That works for me.  Please show a complete failing example.

Comment: That JSON is invalid. How are you parsing it?

Comment: He probably doesn't have JSON like that but just a JS object.. or whatever his debug tools shows when printing the object on the console.

Comment: @gp: yes it is. if the key is quoted pretty much anything is legal

Comment: @gp, that's valid. I was referring to some of the keys not being enclosed by quotes.

Comment: the json is invalid. there is extra '}' at the end. i removed it and it works fine. f.feed.$ also works

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, 

I found the issue, 
$ is another element of feed and not related to title
also title is an array object
Therefore, f.feed.$.title would not work.

But, f.feed.title[0] worked and returned the feed title as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `}` at the end of your JSON object.

Comment: seems to be the right answer, but to be pedantic: it's not a JSON object. It's just an object. It doesn't meet the criteria to be JSON syntax (must use double quotes, must quote all keys).

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, 

I found the issue, 
$ is another element of feed and not related to title
also title is an array object
Therefore, f.feed.$.title would not work.

But, f.feed.title[0] worked and returned the feed title as expected.